# How to skip comments line in data file I want to import, with R

Tags: r, matrix, import, line, skip

I've many string files (.str), and I want to import them in R (looping on files).
The problem is that the first line is neither columns name nor the beginning of the matrix.. It is a comment line. Idem for the last line.
between those two lines, stand up the matrix I want to import..
How can I do that ?

Thx

Comment: Welcom to SO. Please read this on how to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In this case for example, you should add some parts of your text, then what have you tried.

Comment: Are they preceeded by any kind of comment character?

Comment: Read `?read.table`. The parameters `skip`, `nrow`, and `comment.char` might be relevant to you.

Comment: If the files don't all have identical structure, you can always read in with `readLines` and then use regexp functions to remove lines you don't want before converting to your intended data structure.

Comment: Thx you guys.. 
Roland, I can't use nrow.. number of rows depends on files, it is variable.

Comment: @user2551551 But if the ***first*** line is the one you want to skip, just use `skip = 1` in `read.table` to jump the first line and carry on as normal, e.g. `read.table( "myfile.txt" , skip = 1 , header = TRUE )`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to skip the first *and* last lines in a file, you can do it as follows. Use `readLines` to read the file into a character vector, and then pass it to `read.csv`.

```
strs <- readLines("filename.csv")
dat <- read.csv(text=strs,             # read from an R object rather than a file
                skip=1,                # skip the first line
                nrows=length(strs) - 3 # skip the last line
                )
```

The `- 3` is because the number of rows of data is 3 less than the number of lines of text in the file: 1 skipped line at the beginning, 1 line of column headers, and 1 skipped line at the end. Of course, you could also just ignore the `nrows` argument, and delete the nonsense row from your data frame after the import.

Answer (score 6):

You can put your comments anywhere in the data files in the same way that you put your comments an `R` script. For example, if I have a `data.txt` like this:

```
# comment 1
str1
str2
# comment 2
str3
# comment 3
str4
str5# comment 4
str6
str7
# comment 5
```

Then you don't need to do anything to skip the comments:

```
> x<-read.table("data.txt", header=FALSE)
> x
    V1
1 str1
2 str2
3 str3
4 str4
5 str5
6 str6
7 str7
>
```

Note that `comment 4` is not read. You can change the comment character `#` by using the `comment.char` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip arbitrary lines anywhere in the file if you combine the `readLines` approach Hong Ooi gives together with negative indexing. Here's an example which skips lines 2-5 in a file that has headers but a number lines of annotation/meta info:

```
lines <- readLines('myfile.txt')
mytable <- read.table(text = lines[-c(2:5)], sep = '\t', header = T)
```

Comment: This does not skip the lines. It reads all the lines, and then removes some of them. If the files are large, this is a bad approach.